# Regular expression problem in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have these strings as a response from a FTP server:

1. `02-17-11  01:39PM       <DIR>          dec`
2. `04-06-11  11:17AM       <DIR>          Feb 2011`
3. `05-10-11  07:09PM                87588 output.xlsx`
4. `06-10-11  02:52PM                3462 output.xlsx`

where the pattern is: `[datetime] [length or <dir>] [filename]`

---

**Edit:** my code was- `@"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}(\s)+(<DIR>|(\d)+)+(\s)+(.*)+"`

I need to parse these strings in this object:

```
class Files{

Datetime modifiedTime,
bool ifTrueThenFile,
string name

}
```

---

Please note that, filename may have spaces.

I am not good at regex matching, can you help?

Comment: What have you tried so far?   Also note, that regex isn't really needed for this.  You could do a very simple parse of this.

Comment: Learn how to do it, try for example here http://www.radsoftware.com.au/articles/regexlearnsyntax.aspx

Comment: A tool I like to use is http://regexhero.net/

Comment: @tster: having error in my regex: `@"^\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}(\s)+(<DIR>|(\d)+)+(\s)+(.*)+"` and set datetime as `time= {0}`...but `time` is empty

Comment: @Damokles: I read and failed. i should have post my code i tried...

Comment: @Jim: require silverlight, i will try it later

Comment: I agree with tster here; this can be easily parsed with a simple split on ' ' and rejoining at the start and end, which should be very clear to anyone maintaining the code in the future.  Regex is quite powerful, but if you don't understand it, what makes you think the maintenance engineer will?  The advantage of Regex in this case is that it can help detect malformed syntax, but you'll be repeating this process anyway when you parse the DateTime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Regex method

One approach is using this regex

```
@"(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}(?:PM|AM)) (<DIR>|\d+) (.+)";
```

I am capturing groups, so

```
// Group 1 - Matches the DateTime
(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}(?:PM|AM))
```

Notice the syntax `(?:xx)`, it means that the content here will not be caught in a group, we need to match `PM` or `AM` but this group alone doesn't matter.

Next I match the file size or `<DIR>` with

```
// Group 2 - Matches the file size or <DIR>
(<DIR>|\d+)
```

Catching the result in a group.

The last part matches directory names or file names

```
// Group 3 - Matches the dir/file name
(.+)
```

Now that we captured all groups we can parse the values:

```
DateTime.Parse(g[1].Value); // be careful with current culture
                            // a different culture may not work
```

To check if the captured entry is a file or not you can just check if it is `<DIR>` or a number.

```
IsFile = g[2].Value != "<DIR>"; // it is a file if it is not <DIR>
```

And the name is just what is left

```
Name = g[3].Value; // returns a string
```

Then you can use the groups to build the object, an example:

```
public class Files
{
    public DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsFile { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Files(GroupCollection g)
    {
        ModifiedTime = DateTime.Parse(g[1].Value);
        IsFile = g[2].Value != "<DIR>";
        Name = g[3].Value;
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var p = @"(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}(?:PM|AM)) (<DIR>|\d+) (.+)";
    var regex = new Regex(p, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var m1 = regex.Match("02-17-11 01:39PM <DIR> dec");
    var m2 = regex.Match("05-10-11 07:09PM 87588 output.xlsx");

    // DateTime: 02-17-11 01:39PM
    // IsFile  : false
    // Name    : dec
    var file1 = new Files(m1.Groups);

    // DateTime: 05-10-11 07:09PM
    // IsFile  : true
    // Name    : output.xlsx
    var file2 = new Files(m2.Groups);
}
```

**Further reading**

- [Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)
- [Regex groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups.aspx)

---

### String manipulation method

Another way to achieve this is to split the string which can be **much faster**:

```
public class Files
{
    public DateTime ModifiedTime { get; set; }
    public bool IsFile { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Files(string line)
    {
        // Gets the date part and parse to DateTime
        ModifiedTime = DateTime.Parse(line.Substring(0, 16));

        // Gets the file information part and split
        // in two parts
        var fileBlock = line.Substring(17).Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2);

        // first part tells if it is a file
        IsFile = fileBlock[0] != "<DIR>";

        // second part tells the name
        Name = fileBlock[1];
    }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // DateTime: 02-17-11 01:39PM
    // IsFile  : false
    // Name    : dec
    var file3 = new Files("02-17-11 01:39PM <DIR> dec");

    // DateTime: 05-10-11 07:09PM
    // IsFile  : true
    // Name    : out put.xlsx
    var file4 = new Files("05-10-11 07:09PM 87588 out put.xlsx");
}
```

**Further reading**

- [String split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)
- [String.Split Method (Char[], Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1bs0eda.aspx)

Comment: Great answer! @seoul Be sure to pass the correct culture to DateTime.Parse() though if your current culture's date format differs from the input. Judging by your name you might originate from Korea in which case the parse will fail. Use `DateTime.Parse(string, new CultureInfo("en-US", true))`

Comment: Very detailed answer :-) thanks @BrunoLM........@Till: Thanks for the tips, although I am not from Korea but the tips is new to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with something like:

```
^(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\s+(\d\d:\d\d[AP]M)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$
```

The first capture group will contain the date, the second the time, the third the size (or `<DIR>`, and the last everything else (which will be the filename).

(Note that this is probably not portable, the time format is locale dependent.)

Comment: Just to explain a bit for regex-beginners: That's a bit more elaborate than mine, though that's not necessary. It also matches with more whitespace between the parts, good thing. It also will fail if the string does not begin with the expression. It does not look strictly for <DIR> or digits but anything other than whitespace. The $ at the end is superfluous since the last characters can be 0 to infinite of anything - so were is the end then? ;)

Comment: Regex.Match(input,"^(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\s+(\d\d:\d\d[AP]M)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$") => `Unrecognized escape sequence`....Do you have any idea why it is not working?

Comment: @seoul: You're missing an `@`

Comment: @seoul Add `@` before your string that may fix your error `Regex.Match(input,@"^(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d)\s+(\d\d:\d\d[AP]M)\s+(\S+)\s+(.*)$")`

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
(\d{2})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2})([AP]M) (<DIR>|\d+) (.+)
```

I used a lot of sub expressions, so it would catch all relevant parts like year, hour, minute etc. Maybe you dont need them all, just remove the brackets in case.

Comment: I don't know leif, but your sequence is also giving error. I worked for last 11 hours and now I am terribly tired to find the error. But thanks for your support :-) I will try it now and tomorrow

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
String regexTemp= @"(<Date>(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\s*\d\d:\d\dA|PM)\s*(<LengthOrDir>\w*DIR\w*|\d+)\s*(<Name>.*)";

Match mExprStatic = Regex.Match(regexTemp, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (mExprStatic.Success || !string.IsNullOrEmpty(mExprStatic.Value))
{
  DateTime _date = DateTime.Parse(mExprStatic.Groups["lang"].Value);
  String lengthOrDir = mExprStatic.Groups["LengthOrDir"].Value;
  String Name = mExprStatic.Groups["Name"].Value;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A lot of good answers, but I like regex puzzles, so I thought I'd contribute a slightly different version...

```
^([\d- :]{14}[A|P]M)\s+(<DIR>|\d+)\s(.+)$
```

For help in testing, I always use this site :  http://www.myregextester.com/index.php

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex here. Why don't you split the string by spaces with a number_of_elements limit:

```
var split = yourEntryString.Split(new string []{" "}, 4, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var date = string.Join(" ", new string[] {split[0], split[1]});
var length = split[2];
var filename = split[3];
```

this is of course assuming that the pattern is correct and none of the entries would be empty.

Comment: It is, as the number of elements is specified to 4 which means the spaces in filename won't matter

Answer (score 0):

I like the regex Leif posted.

However, i'll give you another solution which people will probably hate: fast and dirty solution which i am coming up with just as i am typing:

```
string[] allParts = inputText.Split(" ")
allParts[0-1] = parse your DateTime
allParts[2] = <DIR> or Size
allParts[3-n] = string.Join(" ",...) your filename
```

There are some checks missing there, but you get the idea. 
Is it nice code? Probably not. Will it work? With the right amount of time, surely.
Is it more readable? I tend to to think "yes", but others might disagree.

Comment: Concider that date contains a space.

Comment: doesn't matter, you can still parse it with builtin functions, especially if you know the input format. Edit: Just noticed your answer, and you are removing spaces, which leads to you losing info of the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to implement this with simple string.split, if statement and parse/parseexact method to convert the value. If it is a file then just concatenated the remaining string token so you can reconstruct filename with space